# What does $\leq ^{-1}$ mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definition, relations

Just came across a question on my homework assignment. The only thing it says is:

> What is $\leq ^{-1}$?

It is on chapter for *relations*.

I'm guessing it means:

$R \leq R^{-1}$, for $R$ being a relations, then having $R$ factored out on each sides??

If it helps, the book I'm using is *Mathematics: A Discrete Introduction*, Chapter 14, exercise 14.12

Comment: The [Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) of the relation $R$. Thus $3 \le^{-1}2$ because $2 \le 3$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So "$\leq$" itself is a function already?

Comment: NO. $\le$ is not a function, but a relation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a relation $R$, the relation $R^{-1}$ is another relation:$$a\mathrel{R^{-1}}b\iff b\mathrel Ra.$$